# JAVA Decryption - Reverse engineering an Android application

Tags: android, java

I am trying to decrypt an encrypted string, but I am stuck in `Ciper.doFinal()` where the decryption throws a `BadPaddingException`.
The string in question is **3qBogw/PIqpErH/DyEHLTQ==**. One thing I know is that the string when decrypted contains a number (It is used in `Integer.valueOf()`)

First, the following method is called;

```
public static String getRandom() {
    String str1 = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    String str2 = dCpw^jDyaip^Hfy]XgdRbp_imwbheJCFxTF^ligkteDEdrbtsu\yIV[;
    StringBuilder localStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    localStringBuilder.append(str1);
    localStringBuilder.append(str2);
    return StringUtils.replaceEachRepeatedly(localStringBuilder.toString(), new String[] { "dCp" }, new String[] { "gPs" });
}
```

Nothing too fancy here just creates a UUID and concats it with a constant string and also uses Apache StringUtils to replace all occurances of dCp to gPs - (not sure why that is required)

```
public static String decrypt(String str) {
   try {
      String random = getRandom();
      byte[] decode = Base64.decode(str, 0);
      byte[] array = convertToArray(random);
      return new String(ciperDecrypt(decode, array, array), "UTF-8");
   } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      return "";
   }
}
```

Here in the decrypt method, the generated random value is passed to a method in order to convert it to a byte array. 
Following is that method,

```
private static byte[] convertToArray(String str) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    byte[] obj = new byte[16];
    byte[] bytes = str.getBytes("UTF-8");
    int length = str.length();
    System.arraycopy(bytes, 0, obj, 0, Math.min(bytes.length, obj.length));
    return obj;
}
```

There is nothing fancy here too, just returns a byte array obtained from `String.getBytes()` methods. But what is interesting is that only first 16 bytes are used. This is what worries me, if you look at this carefully, in the `getRandom()` method they concat a `UUID` string and another constant string. But once the same string is passed to this method, the rest of the string is ignored.

And then finally ciperDecrypt method uses a `Ciper` to decrypt the string.

```
public static byte[] ciperDecrypt(byte[] paramArrayOfByte1, byte[] paramArrayOfByte2, byte[] paramArrayOfByte3) {
    try {
        Cipher localCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        SecretKeySpec secret = new SecretKeySpec(paramArrayOfByte2, "AES");
        IvParameterSpec param = new IvParameterSpec(paramArrayOfByte3);
        localCipher.init(2, secret, param);
        return localCipher.doFinal(paramArrayOfByte1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

This procedure looks fine, but when I try to execute it, I get a `BadPaddingException` when the `doFinal()` line is executed. What I suspect is in the creation of the `byte[]` where there is some data loss.

It would be really helpful if anyone can identify where I have gone wrong. 
I would really appreciate it, 
Thanks!

Comment: Adding to my answer - I guess the key really seems to be wrong because it makes no sense. It decrypts a fixed string with a random key (first 16 bytes of the UUID), I don't see how this would ever work without sheer luck.

Comment: Instead of trying to reverse engineer the encryption algorithm, you can try hooking the original decryption function using frida (https://www.frida.re/docs/android/)

Answer (score 1):

I *think* your decryption is wrong, possibly because you use a wrong key.

If I remember correctly, PKCS5 allows you to *kind of* detect faulty decrypts. The reason is that PKCS5 expects decrypted data to be in a special padding format. If your decryption fails, the padding format isn't adhered to and thus it complains about bad padding.

Without having looked it up, an example:

Say I use PKCS5 padding for my input (length 10 bytes) for a block size of 16 bytes. Properly padded it would look like this:

```
Data      xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx 06 06 06 06 06 06
```

The `06` bytes at the end are padding and their value must be how many padding bytes there are.

So if you decrypt something and the last `n` bytes (`n` = byte value of last byte) aren't `n`, PKCS5 will complain about bad padding.

In my experience that happens with faulty decryptions due to wrong key.